# NPM Pack: Rename package directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a small script that uses `npm pack` to package a certain nodejs module. When I unpack the `.tgz` created by the `npm pack` command the directory inside is named `package`. My question is if there's a way to rename this package to the acutal name of the project?

Package.json

```
{
   "name": "package_name",
   "version": "0.0.3",
   "description": "A description",
   "main": "server.js",
   "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
   },
   "author": "",
   "license": "ISC",
   "dependencies": {
      "request": "2.55.0"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
      "grunt": "0.4.5",
      "grunt-contrib-concat": "0.5.1"
   }
}
```

Here's to code I'm using, might be helpful.

```
npm.load('./some/path', function (er) {
    if (er) {
       res.send("er");
    }
    npm.commands.pack(['./another/path'], function (er, data) {
    if (er) {
       res.send("error");
    }

    var fileName = __dirname+"/projectName-0.0.3.tgz";
    res.sendFile(fileName, {
         headers: {
             "Content-Type": "application/x-tar"
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: The tar created by `npm pack` seems required to have a specific format. Since it serves the purpose of becoming public via npm repository

Comment: According to [last commit](https://github.com/npm/npm/commit/f044e9a207c203f335953c1e4c94d74de4c8bfdf) to `pack.js` in npm it is impossible to override this behavior unless you rebuild your own npm

Comment: I have the same question, I opened an issue here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10227

Answer (score 5):

@Kirill Slatin is correct.  The `npm pack` format is intended for internal consumption, so npm does not provide an affordance for changing the name from `package` to something else.

However, you can change the names while extracting if your `tar` supports the `-s` switch.  On OSX, you can do:

`tar -xvz -s/package/foo/ -f foo-1.0.0.tgz`

(Edited, thanks David G for pointing out the error.)

Comment: nnyby points out:

```Using the GNU version of tar, the command is:

 tar --transform='s,package/,foo/,' -xvzf foo-1.0.0.tgz
```

Comment: That should be `tar -xvz -s/package/foo/ -f foo-1.0.0.tgz` (note the extra slash after the sed-like replacement string).

Comment: Thanks! I'm used to vim where the trailing slash is optional.

Comment: But what's the point? In my case `npm install` unpacks theit with `package` folder in the path and then complains that cannot find modules inside it... well... because of extra `package` folder in the path.